# Are you required to call a judge if you're not involved in the game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel, mtg-professional-rel

If you're a spectator to a game at either competitive or professional REL and you see a gamestate error occur, should you call a judge?

What happens if you don't call a judge?

Is it different if you see blatant cheating or bribery instead of a gamestate error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Covered by the [Tournament Rules](http://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Tournament_Rules_PDF1.pdf):

> Any person physically present at a tournament and not in any other category above is a spectator. Spectators are responsible for remaining silent and passive during matches and other official tournament sections in which players are also required to be silent. **If spectators believe they have observed a rules or policy violation, they are encouraged to alert a judge as soon as possible.** At Regular or Competitive REL, spectators are permitted to ask the players to pause the match while they alert a judge. At Professional REL, spectators must not interfere with the match directly.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: So they're encouraged to, but not required to?

Comment: Yep - probably to dodge the question of "how do you punish a spectator?"

Comment: Yes, that's what it says. But that shouldn't be a surprise; the same goes at any other kind of event, and even in society in general. Requiring spectators (or bystanders) to report errors (or crimes) creates a slew of problems. It's best to let moral and societal pressures encourage it.

Comment: In contrast, the Laws of Duplicate {Tournament] Bridge *specifically forbid* kibitzers from any interaction with the players at all during the play of a round, unless at the behest of a Tournament Director (Law 76 B, page 93): http://www.acbl.org/assets/documents/play/Laws-of-Duplicate-Bridge.pdf